# Kubernetes Controller Logging From a Context

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I am writing an Operator for Kubernetes using the Operator SDK and have a question about logging (I am still rather new to Go).

I have setup a logger in my controller that I have attached a UUID to as a Trace ID

```
func (r *MyReconciler) Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
    myLog = log.FromContext(ctx).WithValues("traceID", uuid.NewUUID())
    myCtx := log.IntoContext(ctx, myLog)
```

However I have a Library that is setup at the same time as the controllers and passed in via the struct.

```
type MyReconciler struct {
    MyBase
    MyClient MyGreatClient
}
```

And each method on the client take the ctx as a parameter.

As I want to use the logger in the ctx as it contains my trace ID do I need to add this line to every method in the client or is there a better way to do it?

```
func (mgc *MyGreatClient) SomethingExists(ctx context.Context, something string) bool {
    myGreatClientLog = log.FromContext(ctx).WithName("MyGreatClient")
    myGreatClientLog.Info("Checking Something Exists", "Something", something)
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I am wanting to do? It doesn't appear that `"sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log"` (of type `logr.Logger`) supports just logging a context like zap.

```
 myappcontex.Logger(ctx).Info("did something awesome")
```

Any help on doing this the idiomatic way is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Not at all sure of this answer and I too wonder why logging and logging sinks are built so complex (refer https://dave.cheney.net/2015/11/05/lets-talk-about-logging which I found reffered in logr https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-logr/logr@v0.3.0 !);

This is how I logged in a generated `kubebuilder` operator controller

```
log.Log.Info("Pod Image is set", "PodImageName", testOperator.Spec.PodImage)
```

Ouput-

```
1.6611775636957748e+09  INFO    Pod Image is set        {"PodImageName": "alexcpn/run_server:1.2"}
```

and with this

```
log.FromContext(ctx).Info("Pod Image is ", "PodImageName", testOperator.Spec.PodImage)
```

Ouput is

```
1.6611801111484244e+09  INFO    Pod Image is    {"controller": "testoperartor", "controllerGroup": "grpcapp.mytest.io", "controllerKind": "Testoperartor", "testoperartor": {"name":"testoperartor-sample","namespace":"default"}, "namespace": "default", "name": "testoperartor-sample", "reconcileID": "ffa3a957-c14f-4ec9-8cf9-767c38fc26ee", "PodImageName": "alexcpn/run_server:1.2"}
```

The controller uses Golang Logr

`All logging in controller-runtime is structured, using a set of interfaces defined by a package called logr (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-logr/logr). The sub-package zap provides helpers for setting up logr backed by Zap (go.uber.org/zap)`  https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log#DelegatingLogSink

And I can see that it sets Zap logging in main

```
ctrl.SetLogger(zap.New(zap.UseFlagOptions(&opts)))
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the info that is printed by the logger into a string? ` {"controller": "testoperartor", "controllerGroup": "grpcapp.mytest.io", "controllerKind": "Testoperartor", "testoperartor": {"name":"testoperartor-sample","namespace":"default"}, "namespace": "default", "name": "testoperartor-sample", "reconcileID": "ffa3a957-c14f-4ec9-8cf9-767c38fc26ee", "PodImageName": "alexcpn/run_server:1.2"}`